# Moving an imageview after recieving coordinates from other device in Android

Tags: android

I am developing a game in which an image will be moved in one device should reflect the movement in another device. I am recieving coordinates from first device and storing them on server. And in second device retrieving those coordinates and moving imageview using setX() and setY(). But this movement is not accurate.
Here is my code....

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i += 2) {
    imageView.setX(Float.parseFloat(array[i]));
    imageView.setY(Float.parseFloat(array[i + 1]));
}
```

Comment: Have you corrected the coordinates for the different screen sizes and densities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the 1st device you must be getting values in pixels. You need to convert those into `dp`.

For the 2nd device, as per its device density, convert the `dp` you got above into pixels and pass these pixels value in `setX()` and `setY()`.

`getX()`, `getY()` give pixel values. 
`setX()`, `setY()` take pixel values.

But you cannot use pixels directly for placing an image as depending on a phone's density, it may plot the image in different places.